# Click event on element (displayed only on hover) is not triggered

Tags: jquery, events, hover

I can't get an event to trigger when you click on an element, and this element is only displayed when you hover of a td element.

```
//Hovering over a td element displayed a Span
$('td').hover(
    function() {$(this).append('<span class="editCell">hello</span>')}, 
    function() {$(this).find('span:last').remove()}
)

//Clicking on that span, it's supposed to trigger alert. But it doesn't. 

$('.editCell').click( function(){

    alert('hello');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.click()` event doesn't work on dynamically added content.

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

```
$("td").on("click", ".editCell" ,function(){

});
```

- The first parameter is the event you want to bind.
- The second parameter is the selector, it filters all the elements in `td` and bind `click` event only to that selector.
- The third parameter is the function to call.

The above is called `delegated-events`.

You also can do it like this :

```
$(".editCell").on("click",function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `editCell` element is being appended after page load. You need to delegate the event to the nearest static element. Try this:

```
$("td").on("click", ".editCell", function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```

The `td` selector is still a little broad though, you should put an id on the closest parent of `editCell` for the sake of performance.